# Border Styling with Collapsed Borders

Tags: html, css, deployment

**Issue:**
I am trying to highlight the top and bottom border of items within an accordion when they have hovered state.

The issue is that I use the `border-collapse: collapse` statement to collapse borders that are adjacent. There the hover effects don't resolve the wanted styling.

Below you will find the HTML and CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="accordion-container">
        <tr class="accordionItem-container" v-for="(item, index) in state.topics" :key="index">
            <td class="accordionItem">
                <div class="accordionImage-container">
                    <img class="accordionImage" :src="item.img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="accordionCopy-container">
                    <BaseHeading class="accordionHeader">
                        <template #default>
                            <span class="mainHeader">{{ item.mainHeader }}</span>
                            <span class="subHeader">{{ item.subHeader }}</span>
                        </template>
                    </BaseHeading>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="accordionItem-container" v-for="(item, index) in state.topics" :key="index">
            <td class="accordionItem">
                <div class="accordionImage-container">
                    <img class="accordionImage" :src="item.img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="accordionCopy-container">
                    <BaseHeading class="accordionHeader">
                        <template #default>
                            <span class="mainHeader">{{ item.mainHeader }}</span>
                            <span class="subHeader">{{ item.subHeader }}</span>
                        </template>
                    </BaseHeading>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style scoped>
    .accordion-container {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0 4px;
    }
    .accordionItem-container {
        border: 4px solid #EBEEF0;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
    }
    .accordionItem-container:hover {
        border: 4px solid #006366;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
    }
    .accordionItem {
        display: flex;
        padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
        gap: 20px;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .accordionImage-container {
        width: 61px;
        height: 56px;
    }
    .accordionImage {
        border-radius: 12px;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .accordionHeader {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .mainHeader {
        font-weight: 400 !important;
    }
    .subHeader {
        font-weight: 300 !important;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        .accordionImage-container {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Here is also a link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MarquezTMoore/Lyb5ah7o/6/

I have tried using the `outline` property in the hover state however this add outline to all four sides...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is trying to give the border to the `tr`. Try this instead:
`.accordionItem-container:hover td {}`

CSS Styling Tables
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: The goal is that the gray border should simply turn green.

Comment: You have to apply border styling to the `td`, not the `tr`
        .accordionItem-container:hover td {
        border: 4px solid #006366;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
    }

Answer (score 0):

> It can be achieved use pseudo-elements like after and before

```css
 .accordion-container {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0 4px;
}
.accordionItem-container {
        border: 4px solid #EBEEF0;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        position:relative;
        cursor:pointer;
}

.accordionItem-container:hover:after  {
        width:100%;
}
.accordionItem-container:hover:before  {
        width:100%;
}
.accordionItem-container:after{
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
   height:4px;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   background-color:#006366;
}
.accordionItem-container:before{
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
   height:4px;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   background-color:#006366;
}
```

```html
<table class="accordion-container">
        <tr class="accordionItem-container">
            <td class="accordionItem">
               some content
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="accordionItem-container">
            <td class="accordionItem">
                some content
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="accordionItem-container">
            <td class="accordionItem">
                some content
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The goal is that the gray border should simply turn green.

Comment: yes, it is turning green on hover